# Progressbar decrement using datetime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, progress-bar, decrement

I am trying to decrement timer from 30 minutes to 0 mins and update the progressbar with the decrement of time

I have a progressbar control on my form and set it's  **`min val to '0'`**  and **`max value to '60'`** and **`incremental step to '1'`**

I have stucked with it right now..

This is what I have done so far:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     ProgressBar1.Value = 60
End sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Dim dFrom As DateTime
        Dim dTo As DateTime
        Dim sDateFrom As String = DateTime.Now
        Dim sDateTo As String = lblLogOutTime.Text
        If RemainingTime.Text = "00:00:00" Then
            RemainingTime.Text = "Time's up!"
            ProgressBar1.Value = 0
            Timer2.Stop()
         ElseIf DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, dFrom) AndAlso DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, dTo) Then
            Timer2.Start()
            ProgressBar1.Value -= 1
            ProgressBar1.Update()
            Dim TS As TimeSpan = dTo - dFrom
            Dim hour As Integer = TS.Hours
            Dim mins As Integer = TS.Minutes
            Dim secs As Integer = TS.Seconds
            Dim timeDiff As String = ((hour.ToString("00") & ":") + mins.ToString("00") & ":") + secs.ToString("00")
            RemainingTime.Text = timeDiff
 End If
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a lot of extra code in there.  For instance DateTime types converted to string, then back to Date.

```
Private LogOutTime as Date          ' destination time
```

Form Load/Restart sub:

```
LogOutTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30)
' 1 min tick
Timer2.Interval = 60 * 1000         ' 1 min timer
ProgressBar1.Value = 30             ' 30 min countdown
ProgressBar1.Maximum = 31 
Timer2.Start

 Private Sub Timer2_Tick(...

    Dim Ts as TimeSpan = LogOutTime - DateTime.Now

    If Ts.Minutes = 0 Then           ' or TS,Ticks
        RemainingTime.Text = "Time's up!"
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        Timer2.Stop()
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' better to convert Ts.Ticks to a 0-30 value
    ' so the timer interval can be different than 1 min
    ProgressBar1.Value -= 1
    RemainingTime.Text = New DateTime(Ts.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:ss")
    Timer2.Start()

  End Sub
```

There are several ways to format the time remaining depending on your .NET version.  I dont know what Timer1 does, it might interfere.  If the Timer interval was 20 or 30 secs you could show seconds ticking away but you'd have to calculate the progressbar value from Timespan.Ticks rather than simply decrement.